# Extract value of attribute 'style'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Simple question really, but somehow, I can't figure it out. 
I have the following, let's call it "s":

```
<tr>
  <td class="some_class">
    <span class="outer_class">
       <span class="inner_class" style="width:86.0px"></span>
    </span>
  </td>
<td>Variable_name</td>
</tr>
```

I want to extract the value of "style", ie. 86.0px (text or string, I don't care).

I have tried:

```
s.find(attrs={"style"})
```

but it returns "None" (but it exists, worst case scenario, it has value 0.0). 
and `.contents` returns the entire value between tags.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

```
width_long=s.find_all('tr')[0].find_all('span')[1].get('style')
```

Needed to ask to find the answer, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can [pass a filter function to the `soup.find` function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

```
s.find(lambda tag:tag.has_attr('style')).get('style')
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe: 
var sd = document.querySelectorAll('.inner_class'),
widthValue = sd[0].attributes['style'].value.replace('width:', '');

Answer (score 0):

This can return a list of style of all spans:

```
allSpanStyle = map(lambda x: x.get('style'), s.find_all("span"))
notNoneStyle = [x for x in allSpanStyle if x is not None]
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the style is an unicode string. You have to use Regular Expression or handcrafted program to parse it.

Comment: Thanks. I don't  mind playing a bit with regular expression or some manual string manipulation as long as the format is consistent (and in this case, it will be).